# How to average two values inside a single column with pandas in an iterative way?

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I'm trying to process some data in python using pandas to create a dataframe, but I'm having trouble to manipulate the data inside each column. What I need to do, essentially is, for every column in the dataframe that is not [Depth], check for every value in the column if it is above the 95th percentile. If so, the value has to be replaced with the average of the one previous and the one following.

I wanted to use a functions to do the first part and then have it iterate for each column... but it's not really working and I'm not sure why.

The code so far is

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

'''
Function do remove the "spikes", data points above the 95th percentile
'''

def removespikes (x):
perc = np.percentile(x, 95)
for i in x:
    if i == 0 or x <= perc:
        pass
    else:
        i = mean(i-1, i+1)
    return x

df=pd.read_excel(r"Dati.xlsx")

for column in df:
if column == 'Depth':
    pass #there is no need to do it for the column Depth
else:
    col = df[column]
    col = removespikes(col)

plt.plot(df['Depth'], x, color=colline,
   marker='o', ms=1.0,
   linestyle='-', lw=0.2)
   plt.savefig('{}.png'.format(column))
   plt.clf()
```

The last part is the plotting part, but it's not really giving me any problems... any advice? I know there are easier way to do it (for once, using excel itself) but since I'm trying to learn python, I'm trying to force myself to use it...

The data I'm using can be found at this dropbox
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/n0j2fvvlsipzrblj8c45t/Dati.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=xgpsxvjfpmvl71ivfbe72b235)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your approach correctly, then I notice the following main problems in your code:

- Firstly, in your `removespikes()` function, **`x` is a column of values**, and so comparing it to `perc`, which is a single value, doesn't work. Instead, I would use compare each value in the column to `perc` during each iteration.
- Furthermore, **`i` in your loop is a value in the column `x`**. Performing the `mean` on `i-1` and `i+1` is not accessing the previous and next items in the column as you mentioned you are trying to do (it is actually returning the same value back to you). My approach would be to use `enumerate` to retrieve the index of each value in the column, as well as the value itself, and then call `mean(x[index-1], x[index+1])`, which accesses the previous and next items in `x`.
- When plotting, you pass `x` to `plt.plot()`, but `x` is a local variable within `removespikes()`, and so it is not accessible outside that function. I assume you want to plot the new columns against Depth, and so I would move the plotting to inside the loop as displayed below, with the parameter `col` in place of `x`.

Here are the implemented changes

```
def removespikes(x):
    perc = np.percentile(x, 95)
    for index, value in enumerate(x):
        if index == 0 or value <= perc or index == len(x)-1:
            pass
        else:
            value = mean(x[index-1], x[index+1])
            x[index] = value
    return x

for column in df:
    if column == 'Depth':
        pass #there is no need to do it for the column Depth
    else:
        col = df[column]
        col = removespikes(col)
        plt.plot(df['Depth'], col, marker='o', ms=1.0,linestyle='-', lw=0.2)
```

Apologies if I have misunderstood your question at all. I hope this helps!

Comment: Actually, you understood it completely! And yeah, looking back at it my code is completely nonsensical D: thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I know the title says "in an iterative way" but you cloud do it also like...

```
import pandas as pd


def removespikes(frame, column: str, limiter: float = 95., inter_limit: int = 1, inplace=False):
    if not inplace:
        frame = frame.copy()
# filter the cloumn and replace all values greater than 95 with NaN
    frame[column][frame[column] > limiter] = pd.np.nan
#interpolte missing data (max. linear interpolation , from both sides, see test frame)
    frame[column].interpolate(limit=inter_limit, limit_direction='both', limit_area='inside', inplace=True)
    if not inplace:
        return frame

# test dataframe
perc = [80, 85, 96, 85, 87, 90, 96, 96, 94, 82, 91, 96, 96, 96, 94]
depth = list(range(len(perc)))

df = pd.DataFrame({'perc': perc, 'Depth': depth})

removespikes(df, 'perc', inplace=True)
#plot all cloumns, exclude "Depth"
df.loc[:, df.columns != 'Depth'].plot(marker='o', ms=1.0, linestyle='-', lw=0.2)
```